# list out of range error when python-docx reads a table of which the border's not aligned

Tags: python, python-docx

I am parsing a table (which looks like the image below) in Word docx file by using python-docx. But when it reads the table below it throws an error.
I've noticed that there is a tiny "crack" at the right-end border of the table as I circled red in the picture. If I manually align the right-end border, my code will be fine. But isn't there a clever way to solve it?

```
from docx import Document
document = Document(u'D:\\1.docx')
tables = document.tables
print(tables[0].rows[0].cells[0].text)
```

[image: table in my docx file]

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda2\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2862, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-168-61cbbaa7e1a8>", line 1, in <module>
    tables[0].rows[0].cells[0].text
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda2\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\docx\table.py", line 384, in cells
    return tuple(self.table.row_cells(self._index))
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda2\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\docx\table.py", line 106, in row_cells
    return self._cells[start:end]
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda2\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\docx\table.py", line 173, in _cells
    cells.append(cells[-col_count])
IndexError: list index out of range
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda2\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2808, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda2\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2879, in run_code
    self.showtraceback(running_compiled_code=True)
TypeError: showtraceback() got an unexpected keyword argument 'running_compiled_code'
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. We don't have the table to test on, so any answer at best is going to be a guess.

Comment: how to attach an attachment?

Comment: You can't. You could try creating a small program for generating the example table that you showed.

Comment: it's not possible to generate the table by code. it's a table from a report documented in a docx file. what i'm doing is to write a python code to process those tables in the report. but there is one such table that's so strange which makes the error.